# Un-numbered Clause for Preamble in scrjura

Tags: numbering, scrjura

In a contract, I'd like a preamble that behaves just like a `\Clause` except that its heading shouldn't have a § symbol or a number in front of it.
Also, the next Clause should be numbered 1, not 2, but I know that can be done by resetting the Clause counter (`\setcounter{Clause}{0}`)

Essentially, I'm looking for an equivalent of `\section*` for `\Clause`s, but `\Clause*` isn't defined.

Comment: Do you mean inside or outside the `contract` environment? "The clauses within these environments are treated as if they were within a single environment. As a result, ending the environment really only temporarily interrupts it, and the old environment is continued by the beginning of a new environment." - scrguien.pdf, p314.

Comment: Note: "Empty numbers [for a clause] are not possible." p316.

Comment: Well, the cleanest solution would be to have that unnumbered Clause inside the `contract` environment; that would ensure that all the formatting really is the same for the preamble as for the rest.  I could have a `\Section*` before the `clause` and make sure its contents look the same, but that'll cause inconsistencies if I change anything that applies only to `contract` material.

Comment: Try `\newcommand*{\Clauseformat}[1]{}`, and then `\newcommand*{\Clauseformat}[1]{\S~#1}\setcounter{Clause}{0}` clause 1, then `\newcommand*{\Clauseformat}[1]{\S~#1}` clause 2. Alternatively, print Clause 0 \S~#1 as white text format, then reset format and counter.

Comment: I just tried starting with a `\section` outside the `contract` and a ` \Clause{dummy}` but apparently `\Clause{dummy}` doesn't seem to start off paragraph numbering like `\Clause{title=Something}` does.

Comment: Clause and auto paragraph numbering only work inside the contract environment (p314).

Comment: What I did was:
```\section*{Preamble}
\begin{contract}
\Clause{dummy}
Dolor sit amet...
`
but that didn't cause paragraphs to be numbered.